# How to get select from SQL Server for multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sql-server-2008, select

I have a C# program that selects all of the rows of a table with about 100 million rows, and performs some analysis on each row. The analysis of each row is independent from that on every other row. I would like to make my app multithreaded in order to speed up computation (I am running on a dual-processor quad-core Intel Xeon). I would like, for two threads, that one thread select the first half (about 50 million) of the rows and that other thread select the second half of the rows. What is the most efficient way to do this? My rows all have primary ids. My program right now jsut runs `select * from table`.

Comment: If computation of one row depends on other row it could happens that first thread need data captured by the second thread so there are could be problems

Comment: This sounds more indicative of a design problem than a code problem. Is this computation something that cannot be done in SQL? If you just want to partition the size of your result set, why not simply to `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table` and then make resulting `SELECT TOP X FROM Table` and `SELECT BOTTOM X FROM Table` queries?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using LINQ and .NET 4.0? If so, you can leverage [Parallel Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425.aspx) to do what you want easily.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this?

```
select * from table where id % 2 = 0
select * from table where id % 2 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to determine where the bottleneck is. Is your select statement taking 10 seconds to execute, but your code analysis is taking milliseconds? Or is it the other way around?

I would put some metrics together for everything you have going on before attempting to jump head first in to multi-threading.  I think you'll find your C# code is going to be very fast and that your SQL is going to slow you down.  Look into optimizing your SQL and your database first.

Comment: My select statement takes ten minutes to execute, while the analysis takes less than a minute. If I have two select statements running in parallel, will SQL Server launch another thread to select them more quickly?

Comment: Yeah, you're looking at a SQL Server/ADO .NET issue. I'm curious to see what kind of a solution  you come up with.  I'll research it some too and get back to this if I find something worth noting.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the analysis in the query itself. It might be a lot faster than returning the rows and running the analysis locally.